# Docker processes show via host ps -a?

Tags: linux, docker

I'm surprised to find processes spawned within a Docker container show up when running ps -a on the host.

My question is: is this expected behavior?

Comment: Yes, it is expected behavior.

Comment: Please explain. On OSX and Windows there's no "mix" of host and container processes. For the first time runnning docker on Linux I was wondering too about this strange behavior. So my favorite to running docker due to this reason is to use OSX or Windows.